# rails web pack react - sprocket couldn't find file react-server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, sprockets

I am trying to install react through webpack using rails 4.2.7

I followed this one https://github.com/rails/webpacker and stuck with the error

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound at /
couldn't find file 'react-server' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /Users/dev/Documents/ff/app/assets/images
  /Users/dev/Documents/ff/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/dev/Documents/ff/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/dev/Documents/ff/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/dev/Documents/ff/vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

it's nothing to do with webpack, I have installed react-rails earlier and those files conflicted with webpack. Completely removed the older react-rails files and got it working.