# Sprockets::FileNotFound at / couldn't find file 'react-server' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, react-redux, react-server

I'm returning to a website that I made about a year and a half ago, and when spinning up the rails server, I get this error:

**Sprockets::FileNotFound at /
couldn't find file 'react-server' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths:** [bunch of file paths...]

The errors looks the same as this issue:
[rails web pack react - sprocket couldn't find file react-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240966/rails-web-pack-react-sprocket-couldnt-find-file-react-server)

The previous post talks about removing old react rails files, but I don't know which files that would be referring to.

---

RESOLVED

---

In the end, it was one installation and one gemfile addition that did the trick. I ran: npm install --save react-server, and then I added: gem 'react-rails', to my gemfile, then of course ran bundle exec install.

Comment: In the end, it was one installation and one gemfile addition that did the trick. I ran: npm install --save react-server, and then I added: gem 'react-rails', to my gemfile, then of course ran bundle exec install.

Answer (score -1):

In the file server-rendering.js delete or comment those lines:

```
//= require react-server
//= require react_ujs
//= require ./components
```